# How do I check a binary exists in the PATH in a Vim plugin?

Tags: vim

I'm writing a Vim plugin.  I need to call a binary which should be in the PATH.  But I want to display an error message if its not.  Whats the best way to find out if the binary is in the PATH?

I'm hoping to find a solution that is portable across different operating systems.  But that doesn't seem very easy and I'll settle for a solution that works on unix/linux/mac.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Check this: `:help executable()`